# Mutating based on multiple columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

Ok so my dataframe looks like this let's call if df

```
KEY   A1  A2  A3 A4  B1 B2 B3 B4 C1  C2  C3  C4
1     120 100 NA 110 1  1  NA  1  NA NA NA NA
2     100 NA 115 NA  NA NA NA NA  Y  N   Y N
```

So what I'm trying to do is make it so that when an A columns has a value of 100 and the corresponding B or C column has a value of 1 or "Y" respectively that makes a new column with a X with a value of 1. In Row 1 that would be A2 and B2 and in row that would be A1 and C1.

I tried doing three sets of gather and then using the mutate function using case_when. like so

```
df<- df %>%
  gather(key="A",value="code",dx)%>%
  gather(key="B",value="number",dxadm)%>%
  gather(key="C",value="character",dxpoa) %>%
  mutate(X=case_when(
    code == 100 & present >0 ~ 1,
    code ==100 & character == "Y"~1)
  )
```

Except my spread function of these rows came back with rows all array and my X out of place.

Alternatively, I considered something like

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(X=case_when(
    A1 == 100 & B1 >0 ~ 1,
    A1 ==100 & C1 == "Y"~1,
    A2 == 100 & B2 >0 ~ 1,
    A2 ==100 & C2 == "Y"~1,)
```

and so on for all permutations. The two problems with this are that I have a lot of columns and I'd like to this for multiple different values of A.

Can anyone recommend an alternative or at least a way to make the second solution into something that would only require one annoying long piece of code that I could make into a more generalizable function? Thanks!

Comment: Also, btw, I was once told (only recently actually) that it is not recommended to use function names such as 'df' for your data frame

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion

```
require(read.so) #awesome package to read from Stackoverflow, 
# available on GitHub [https://alistaire47.github.io/read.so/][1]
require(tidyr)
require(reshape2)
require(dplyr)

dat <- read.so()    

dat %>% gather(var, value, 2:13) %>% #make it long
  mutate(var = gsub('([A-Z])', '\\1_', .[['var']])) %>% #add underscore
  separate(var, c('var', 'number') ) %>% #separate your column 
  dcast(KEY+number ~ var) %>% #dcast is a bit complex but quite powerful
  group_by(KEY) %>% 
  filter(A == 100) 

# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   KEY [2]
    KEY number A     B     C    
  <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 2      100   1     <NA> 
2     2 1      100   <NA>  Y
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr). We can `gather` all the columns except `KEY`, `separate` the letters and numbers, and then `spread` the letter so that we can create the `X` column without specifying the numbers. Notice that I assume if the condition is not met, `X` would be `0`, and based on your description, I used `any(A %in% 100 & (B %in% 1 | C %in% "Y"))` to test the condition as any given numbers met the condition, `X` would be `1`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -KEY) %>%
  separate(Column, into = c("Letter", "Number"), sep = 1) %>%
  spread(Letter, Value, convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(KEY) %>%
  mutate(X = ifelse(any(A %in% 100 & (B %in% 1 | C %in% "Y")), 1L, 0L)) 

df2 %>% as.data.frame()
#   KEY Number   A  B    C X
# 1   1      1 120  1 <NA> 1
# 2   1      2 100  1 <NA> 1
# 3   1      3  NA NA <NA> 1
# 4   1      4 110  1 <NA> 1
# 5   2      1 100 NA    Y 1
# 6   2      2  NA NA    N 1
# 7   2      3 115 NA    Y 1
# 8   2      4  NA NA    N 1
```

I think the structure of `df2` is good, but if you really want the original structure, we can do the following.

```
df3 <- df2 %>%
  gather(Letter, Value, A:C) %>%
  unite(Column,  Letter, Number, sep = "") %>%
  spread(Column, Value) %>%
  select(names(df), X)
df3 %>% as.data.frame()
#   KEY  A1   A2   A3   A4   B1   B2   B3   B4   C1   C2   C3   C4 X
# 1   1 120  100 <NA>  110    1    1 <NA>    1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 1
# 2   2 100 <NA>  115 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    Y    N    Y    N 1
```

`df3` is the final output.

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = "KEY   A1  A2  A3 A4  B1 B2 B3 B4 C1  C2  C3  C4
1     120 100 NA 110 1  1  NA  1  NA NA NA NA
                 2     100 NA 115 NA  NA NA NA NA  Y  N   Y N",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I think I understand but why does your df2 have all of X as 1s? Most of the conditions should have returned zeros. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious. Also what purpose does group_by serve? I'm assuming in the formation of df3 that select is just being used to reorder the columns? Thanks!

Comment: I simply followed your logic. The output of your second code chunk looks the same as my df3, so I think the rule is for every key, if any pair of A, B, or C meet the condition, X would be 1. If you want to evaluate every pair, then just remove group_by and any, but it would make no sense to create df3.

Comment: Although the same idea, I agree that @www 's code is shorter than mine, thanks to the neat use of `separate` and `spread` .Learnt sth too :)

Comment: @Tjebo Thanks. But I have a question. Why yours and Nettle's answer did not generate the column `X` that the OP wants? Your final output does not look like OP's desired output.

Comment: sure, I agree and that’s another reason why your answer it the best one here ;)

Comment: @Tjebo Thanks. I like your answer, too. I think all our ideas are similar and probably useful to OP. It just difficult to know what the OP really wants. If the OP wants to evaluate the condition of each pair, such as `A1-B1-C1`, `A2-B2-C2`, ..., I imagined that the final output should be something like `X1`, `X2` to show the result of each pair. But the OP just wants one `X` column. I guess that is why you and Nettle use `filter` to reduce the number of rows, while I use `group_by` and `any` to evaluate if any pairs meet the condition.

Comment: I can agree both your answers were super helpful and both helped me learn a ton! You're right I did want exactly what you made with a single X column. I also agree that normally it'd be better to leave it as df2 but another bit of code someone else wrote requires the data to look like df3. Thank you both so much though for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as Tjebo, but sticking to the tidyverse....

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
         KEY = c(1L, 2L),
          A1 = c(120L, 100L),
          A2 = c(100L, NA),
          A3 = c(NA, 115L),
          A4 = c(110L, NA),
          B1 = c(1L, NA),
          B2 = c(1L, NA),
          B3 = c(NA, NA),
          B4 = c(1L, NA),
          C1 = c(NA, "Y"),
          C2 = c(NA, "N"),
          C3 = c(NA, "Y"),
          C4 = c(NA, "N"))

dat %>% 
  gather(var, value, -KEY) %>% #make it long
  extract(var, regex = "(.)(.)", into = c("var", "number") ) %>% 
  spread(var, value) %>% 
  filter( A %in% 100 )

#>   KEY number   A    B    C
#> 1   1      2 100    1 <NA>
#> 2   2      1 100 <NA>    Y
```

Created on 2018-02-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: thanks for the reference :) Your way of separating the column is more elegant than mine, for sure, and nice use of spread.